# SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out Android ksoap

Tags: android, soap, ksoap

I´m using ksoap to connect toa webservice but I have a problem when I try to get a value from my webservice.

I got this error exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

I already check the timeout solution and it still doesn´t work

Also I've already made sure that my METHOD,NAMESPACE and URL are correct according to my WSDL file.

Do you have any other solution?

Here is my code:

class SegundoPlano extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        logeo();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


        if (Re.compareTo("true") == 0) {
            //   try {
            Intent I = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
            I.putExtra("folioen", Usuario);
            startActivity(I);

            // }
            // catch (Exception ex)
            //{
            //    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            // }
        }
    }
}


private String logeo() {
    String mensaje;
    String URL = "http://www.example.com/Servicios_web/WebService.asmx";
    String metodo = "Acceso";
    String namespace = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String Accion = "http://tempuri.org/Access";
    try {
        SoapObject obtencion = new SoapObject(namespace, metodo);
        obtencion.addProperty("usuario", User);
        obtencion.addProperty("contra", Password);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(obtencion);
        //HttpsTransportSE transporte = new KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE("192.168.4.38",440,"SERVIEPATH",7000);
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 100000);
        transporte.call(Accion, soapEnvelope);
        SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
        mensaje = resultado.toString();
        Re = resultado.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        mensaje = ex.getMessage();
    }

    return mensaje;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure following is valid soap service URL?

```
String URL = "http://www.example.com/Servicios_web/WebService.asmx";
```

Do you have stack trace of where the call fails?

Comment: I already tried running my app in a mobile which has the Android 7.1 and it´s run succesfully. Then I tried with another phone which has the same version and it throws me the same error. What can I do?